# Where to put the pronoun in a sentence when using the gerund verb form?

Tags: pronouns, gerunds

Which sentence is correct?

> it seems we are all living in a weird land

or

> it seems we all are living in a weird land

?

Comment: Personal preference.  The first is slightly more idiomatic.

Comment: It's the placement of _all_ that's at issue; this has nothing to do with pronouns or gerunds (there are no gerunds in the sentence). Quantifiers like _all_ can appear before any verb phrase, which means that if there are two verbs (as here,  _are_ and _living_), each heads its own verb phrase and _all_ may appear before either one. Notice that the subject (_we_) stays in the same place, as does every other word in the sentence -- only _all_ moves. And it would move without pronouns or progressives.

Comment: living is not gerund? :/